# JSON inside a Loop

Tags: php, json

The code's that I have is executing fine but after I included the loop that was suggested to me the problem is that the data it retrieves shows only `[Object Object]`

here is my current progress

```
      $sql6="SELECT msgid FROM thread WHERE combination1=:msgids OR combination2=:submsgids";
      $msg_id = $con4->prepare($sql6);
      $msg_id->bindParam(':msgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $msg_id->bindParam(':submsgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $msg_id->execute();
      $msgd = $msg_id->fetchColumn();
      $tbpre = $msgd;
    $sql7 = "SELECT   message_content, username , message_time, recipient FROM ".$tbpre."chat_conversation WHERE msgid=:chat";

    $stmt7=$con3->prepare($sql7);
    $stmt7->bindValue( 'chat', $msgd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt7->execute();

  $message_query = $stmt7;

$json = array();

if($message_query->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($message_array = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = $message_array;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Here is my JS

```
    function AjaxRetrieve()
        {
          var rid = document.getElementById('trg').value,
    data = {chat: uid, rid: rid, name: user};

$.get('includes/getChat.php', data, function (result) {
    var res = $([]);

    $.each(result[0], function(key, value) {
        res = res.add($('<div />', {text : value}));
    });

    $("#clog").html(res);

}, 'json');
        }
```

Comment: You will get `[Object Object]` as its an array of an object. Post your js code please.

Comment: ok.. I have posted it =)

Answer (score 0):

`res` is a jQuery object (as created by `$([])` and populated by `res.add`

You're outputting an object into a string context (HTML) so of course it will result in `[object Object]` - that's just how objects are converted to string.

Consider... not using jQuery where it's not needed.

```
var res = [], out = document.getElementById('clog'), div;
while(out.firstChild) out.removeChild(out.firstChild);
$.each(result[0], function(key, value) {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value});
    res.push(div);
    out.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Hi I've tried it and sadly Its the same, the result gave me `[object Object]` =(

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your input array in php side. And show it. Second step is to RE-CHECK manual on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and look on **depth** param.

JS side won't help if you sending wrong params/array/json.